# Using cv2 to read/resize files

Tags: python, opencv

I want to use `cv2` to read/resize files and an error appears.

How can I fix this error?

**Error**: `OpenCV(4.4.0) ..\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:3929: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'`

**Code**:

```
def read_and_process_image(list_of_images):
    """
    Returns two arrays: 
        X is an array of resized images
        y is an array of labels
    """
    X = [] # images
    y = [] # labels
    
    for image in list_of_images:
        X.append(cv2.resize(cv2.imread(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR), (nrows,ncolumns), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC))
        #get the labels
        if 'car' in image:
            y.append(1)
        elif 'neg' in image:
            y.append(0)
    
    return X, y

X, y = read_and_process_image(train_imgs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're failing to read the image, most likely you're not giving the full path of the image to the cv2.imread function, so the cv2.resize function receives None

You need something like this:

```
cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_path, image), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

Make sure you `import os` first at the top of your code.

Fill `image_path` variable with the path of the image.

Comment: You need the actual path to the image in order to load it, that's why this error message occurs as it it fails to read the image.

Comment: but that last command was combining images of cars and images without cars, 2000 of them each  by reading the labels , when i use print(train_imgs) i get a list of combined images , but as you said cv2 cant access it. sorry , complete novice here

Comment: No worries, if this managed to help you kindly accept this answer. :)

Comment: Can you elaborate more on where are the images stored as in the full path to them so that i could help you make it work ?

Comment: It worked , that '../Potsdam/train/{}' was changed to full path +>  C:/Bla/bla....